# I can't get an application to run on Windows startup ASM (Registry)

Tags: c, assembly, regedit, fasm, autorun

I am trying to translate a code made in C into assembly (FASM) but I can't get it to work. The code tries to create an entry in the registry so that when the machine starts it is executed.

Code in C that works perfectly:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      HKEY hkey = NULL;
      
      const char* exe = "C:\\2022-05-14-program\\init.exe";
    
      // startup
      LONG res = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, (LPCSTR)"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0 , KEY_WRITE, &hkey);
      if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        // create new registry key
        RegSetValueEx(hkey, (LPCSTR)"hack", 0, REG_SZ, (unsigned char*)exe, strlen(exe));
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Code in assembly (FASM) that does not work:

```
        .data
          hkey      dd      0
          exe       db      'C:\2022-05-14-program\init.exe'
          cad       db      'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',0
          name      db      'hack2',0
    
          KEY_WRITE         = 0x00020006
          HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 80000001h
          REG_SZ            = 1
    start :
          push hkey    ; Address of DWORD for the handle value.
          push KEY_WRITE
          push 0
          push cad
          push HKEY_CURRENT_USER
          push [RegOpenKeyEx]
    
          push 30      ; Equivalent "SIZE" in fasm?
          push exe
          push REG_SZ
          push 0
          push name
          push [hkey]  ; The actual handle value (not its address!)
          call [RegSetValueEx]
    
          push [hkey]
          call [RegCloseKey]
    
          push 0       ; Errorlevel.
          call [ExitProcess]
    .end start
```

I can see that in the C code it loads perfectly but in the assembly code it doesn't. For this I used the following PowerShell command:

```
reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /s
```

Compiles perfectly but no log entry is generated, I hope someone helps me.

Comment: It does not work at all, or maybe some compiler errors?

Comment: The asm code doesn't distinguish between hkey and &hkey.

Comment: And what would be your distinction? since &hkey is expected

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `push [RegOpenKeyEx]` you should `call [RegOpenKeyEx]`.

Also look at your data in debugger. Windows API expects single backslash in path, check whether your assembler uses **\** as an escape character, like C does.

I have tried it in my [toolchain](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/) and it worked:

```
; Source saved as pabeni.asm
; Created with "euroasm.exe pabeni.asm"
; Debugged with "ollydbg.exe pabeni.exe"
; Checked with "regedt32.exe"
       EUROASM
pabeni PROGRAM FORMAT=PE, ENTRY=start
[.data]
      hkey      dd      0
      exe       db      'C:\2022-05-14-program\init.exe'
      cad       db      'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',0
      name      db      'hack2',0
KEY_WRITE         = 0x00020006
HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 80000001h
REG_SZ            = 1
      IMPORT RegOpenKeyExA,RegSetValueExA,RegCloseKey,LIB=Advapi32.dll
      IMPORT ExitProcess,LIB=kernel32.dll
[.text]
start:
      push hkey       ; Address of DWORD for the handle value.
      push KEY_WRITE
      push 0
      push cad
      push HKEY_CURRENT_USER
      call RegOpenKeyExA

      push SIZE# exe ; 30 characters. Not zero-terminated.
      push exe
      push REG_SZ
      push 0
      push name
      push [hkey]   ; The actual handle value (not its address!)
      call RegSetValueExA
      push [hkey]
      call RegCloseKey
      push 0   ; Errorlevel.
      call ExitProcess
     ENDPROGRAM pabeni
```

Comment: fasm does use `\ ` as an escape character, so the strings are fine

Comment: I have changed the push for the call and it still does not work, thanks for the note I was wrong

Comment: @pabeni Check the value returned from [RegOpenKeyEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexa) then, and when it's not ERROR_SUCCESS=0, search for the cause of error in SDK file `winerror.h`.

Comment: I have done the test and it does not give me an error, can someone be so smable as to try it in their IDE? I don't know what it could be after all the tests carried out

Comment: @pabeni See my edited answer. You pushed the offset of `hkey` before `call RegSetValueEx` instead of its value.

Comment: In Fasm not work:

Comment: In FASM, `push hkey` pushes the address (like NASM).  You should maybe mention that change as well, since that was an actual bug, not a syntax difference between FASM and euroassembler!  Also any other changes you made, like not doing `push eax`.

Comment: to make the changes that @vitsoft told me and it still doesn't work (update the changes above in the post), could it be the strlen function?

Comment: @pabeni Check the assembled strings in your `.data ` section. When FASM uses backslash as an escape, like @LHLauriny says, they are probably assembled incorrectly.  Instead of `strlen` or `size#`  you can manually count characters in `exe` and hardcode them as **cbData** 
 (the last argument of [RegSetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa).)

Comment: @vitsoft he tried with   push exe
      push [lstrlen]
      push eax

Comment: for some reason it does not work in any of the ways, in this post the same thing happens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878942/fasm-adding-to-start-up-hkcu

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it, I attach the code:

```
.data
      hkey      dd      0
      exe       db      'C:\2022-05-14-program\init.exe',0
      cad       db      'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',0
      name      db      'hackoll'
start :
      push hkey    ; Address of DWORD for the handle value.
      push KEY_WRITE
      push 0
      push cad
      push HKEY_CURRENT_USER
      call [RegOpenKeyEx]

      push exe
      call[lstrlen]

      push eax
      push exe
      push REG_SZ
      push 0
      push name
      push [hkey]  ; The actual handle value (not its address!)
      call [RegSetValueEx]

      push [hkey]
      call [RegCloseKey]

      push 0       ; Errorlevel.
      call [ExitProcess]
.end start
```

Thank you all very much for your enormous effort in helping :)